# Onsen UI page navigation with parameters not working

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using Onsen UI and AngularJS, and trying to pass a value on Onsen navigation , but it is not working. What can be wrong?

**page1.html**

```
<ons-button modifier="clean" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true}, {color:'red'})"><img src="red.jpg"></ons-button>

<ons-button modifier="clean" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true}, {color:'blue'})"><img src="blue.jpg"></ons-button>
```

**page2.html**

```
        <p>the color is: {{ color }}!</p>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('colorController', function($scope, colorData) {
    var page = $scope.ons.navigator.getCurrentPage();
    $scope.color = page.options.color;
});
```

When I run it, the page2 at `<p>***{{ color }}***</p>` does not display the color based on clicked button (**red** or **blue**). It displays only **the color is: !**

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass options with a Sliding Menu and read them with a Navigator. There is no `menu.getCurrentPage()` in Sliding Menu so you have to use a Navigator for that. It's possible to emulate it using `navigator.resetToPage()` method instead of `menu.setMainPage()`. First, you need a Navigator as a child of your Sliding Menu:

```
<ons-sliding-menu
  menu-page="menu.html" main-page="navigator.html" var="menu" ...>
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="navigator.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-navigator var="navi" page="main.html"></ons-navigator>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Then, in the menu:

```
<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item onclick="navi.resetToPage('main.html'); menu.close()">Main</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item onclick="navi.resetToPage('page.html', {param1: 'hoge', param2: 'fuga'}); menu.close()">Page with params</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Now you can access to the parameters with `navi.getCurrentPage().options`.
Working in this codepen: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/OyvvGZ

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time in replying my question. But unfortunatelly it still does not works. May there something wrong with page 2  `<p>the color is: {{ color }}!</p>` or the **js** file?

Comment: @PLazzo Oh! I didn't realize you were using both `ons-sliding-menu` and `ons-navigator`. I just edited the answer with working code.